# how to add rightbarbuttonitem from within a subview

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode

I have a view controller, in its viewDidLoad method i add the following subview:

`[self.view addSubview:subViewController.view];`

how can I add a right bar button item to the main view controller navigation bar from withing the viewDidLoad method of the subViewController ?

I tried many combinations like:

`self.parentViewController.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = printButton;`

and

`self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = printButton;`

but didn't work ...

given that the print button shows correctly if I add it from within the viewDidLoad of the main view controller, but I need to display it from within the subView for some reason is that possible or not ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible try this. Use this code to get your superViewController change HomeViewController to your superView's class name

```
         HomeViewController *vController = nil;
         NSArray *vControllers = [self.navigationController viewControllers];
         for(UIViewController *vC in vControllers) {

         if([vC isKindOfClass:[HomeViewController class]]){

             vController = (HomeViewController*)vC;
             break;
            }
         }
//Now assign barbutton item here like 
vController.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = barButton;
```

Let me know if this works or not.

Comment: thanks Rahul for your answer, but it did not work! the button did not shown on the navigation bar of the homeViewController, i put nslog statement inside the if statement you provided but it didn't display on console

Comment: you need to change the class name from homeViewController to your parentViewController's class name.

Comment: I did that of course .. but without any change :( this is weird .. i put nslog statement inside the if statement you provided but it didn't display on console

Comment: You sure you have a navigation controller in your app. Or you just have an navigationBar added using interface builder or by code to your parentview?

Comment: I have a tab bar application, each tab contains a navigation controller (added from IB), one of these tabs is the one Im talking about above

Comment: the tab that im talking about, contains a view controller (which is equivalent to HomeViewController in your example), and inside this view controller there is a subView

Comment: the application is large and can't send the code, i have to make a new app and it takes some time

Comment: Ok. As you have said a viewController so if there is no navigationcontroller the code will not work. You need to change that to navigation controller in interface builder.